# C# Regex capturing group not working

Tags: c#, regex, capturing-group, regex-group

In the following code I want to capture anything that begins with test and followed by the text enclosed by double quotes. E.g.

`test"abc"`

`test"rst"`

The code works fine.

```
private void testRegex()
{
    string st = "this test\"abc\"= or test\"rst\"\"uvw\" or test(def)(abc) is a test.";
    Regex oRegex = new Regex("test\".*?\"");

    foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(st))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
    }
}
```

Then, from the above captures, I want to capture the subexpressions that follow the word test (in above examples those subexpressions would be "abc" and "rst" including the ". I tried the following and it correctly gives me:

`"abc"`

`"rst"`

```
private void testRegex()
    {
        string st = "this test\"abc\"= or test\"rst\"\"uvw\" or test(def)(abc) is a test.";
        Regex oRegex = new Regex("test(\".*?\")");

        foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(st))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mt.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
```

**Question**: Now I want to capture the two subexpressions 1. "abc" and "rst" 2. Any character except " that follows the matches test"abc" and test"rst". So, I tried the following but as shown below the groups 1 and 2 for the match "rst""uvw" are wrong. I need group 1 of "rst""uvw" to be "rst" and group 2 to be empty since the character that follows "rst" is ":

Group 1: "abc"

Group 2: =

Group 1: "rst""

Group 2: u

```
private void testRegex()
        {
            string st = "this test\"abc\"= or test\"rst\"\"uvw\" or test(def)(abc) is a test.";
            Regex oRegex = new Regex("test(\".*?\")([^\"])");

            foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(st))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mt.Groups[1].Value);
                Console.WriteLine(mt.Groups[2].Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be looking for

```
test("[^"]*")([^"])?
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=test(%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22)(%5B%5E%22%5D)%3F&i=this%20test%22abc%22%3D%20or%20test%22rst%22%22uvw%22%20or%20test(def)(abc)%20is%20a%20test.)

I made 2 changes:

- Used negated character class `[^"]*` (matching 0 or more characters other than a double quote) instead of lazy matching any characters with `.*?`
- Made the `[^"]` optional with `?` quantifier.

[image]

Comment: Would have done it exactly the same, except that last `?` it seems to be more intuitive if you put it inside the group.

Comment: Putting the ? inside the group would change the group number of next group (if one exists).  I like the ? outside the group

Comment: @stribizhev, Thanks. It worked. In my C# code I had to escape the " to make it: `test(\"[^\"]*\")([^\"])?`

Comment: @nam: you might as well use a verbatim string literal `var rx = new Regex(@"test(""[^""]*"")([^""])?");`.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternate version:

```
(?<=test)("[^"]+")([^"])?
```

In case you would like to keep result in one place:

```
(?<=test)("[^"]+"[^"]?)
```